# How to Use Elsevier Article Retrieval API to get fulltext of paper

Tags: python, api, article, scopus, httpx

I want to use Elsevier Article Retrieval API (https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/FullTextRetrievalAPI.wadl) to get fulltext of paper.

I use httpx to get the information of the paper,but it just contains some information.My code is below:

```
import httpx
import time


def scopus_paper_date(paper_doi,apikey):
    apikey=apikey
    headers={
        "X-ELS-APIKey":apikey,
        "Accept":'text/xml'
         }

    timeout = httpx.Timeout(10.0, connect=60.0)
    client = httpx.Client(timeout=timeout,headers=headers)
    query="&view=FULL"
    url=f"https://api.elsevier.com/content/article/doi/" + paper_doi
    r=client.get(url)
    print(r)
    return r.text

y = scopus_paper_date('10.1016/j.solmat.2021.111326',myapikey)
y
```

the result is below:

```
<full-text-retrieval-response xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/svapi/article/dtd" xmlns:bk="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/bk/dtd" xmlns:cals="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/cals/dtd" xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd" xmlns:ja="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ja/dtd" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:sa="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-aff/dtd" xmlns:sb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-bib/dtd" xmlns:tb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/table/dtd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xocs="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/xocs/dtd" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><coredata><prism:url>https://api.elsevier.com/content/article/pii/S0927024821003688</prism:url>....
```

how can i get the fulldata of the paper,many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the paper you want to download.

I modified a bit the function you posted. Now it gets the response as JSON and no XML (this is just my personal preference, you can use the format you prefer).

```
import httpx
import time

def scopus_paper_date(paper_doi,apikey):
    apikey=apikey
    headers={
        "X-ELS-APIKey":apikey,
        "Accept":'application/json'
         }
    timeout = httpx.Timeout(10.0, connect=60.0)
    client = httpx.Client(timeout=timeout,headers=headers)
    query="&view=FULL"
    url=f"https://api.elsevier.com/content/article/doi/"+paper_doi
    r=client.get(url)
    print(r)
    return r
```

Now you can retrieve the document you want, and then you will have to parse it:

```
# Get document
y = scopus_paper_date('10.1016/j.solmat.2021.111326',my_api_key)
# Parse document
import json
json_acceptable_string = y.text
d = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
# Print document
print(d['full-text-retrieval-response']['coredata']['dc:description'])
```

The result will the the `dc:description` of the document, i.e. the Abstract:

> The production of molecular hydrogen by photoelectrochemical
> dissociation (PEC) of water is a promising technique, which allows ... The width of the forbidden
> bands and the position of the valence and conduction bands of the
> different materials were determined by Mott - Schottky type
> measurements.

For this document that is all that you can get, there are no more options.
However, if you try to get a different document, for example:

```
# Get document
y = scopus_paper_date('10.1016/j.nicl.2021.102600',my_api_key)
# Parse document
import json
json_acceptable_string = y.text
d = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
```

You can then print the `originalText` key of the `full-text-retrieval-response`

```
# Print document
print(d['full-text-retrieval-response']['originalText'])
```

You will notice that this is a very long string containing a lot of text, probably more that you want, for example it contains all the references as well.

As I said in the beginning, the information you can get depends on the single paper. However, the full data will always be contained in the `y` variable defined in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, but I still have some questions: 

I need submission time data for each article, but I found that there is no corresponding time data in the returned results.

Such as the example:(doi:10.1016/S0014-5793(01)03313-0),the return information include `(<ce:date-received day="6" month="12" year="2001"/>
<ce:date-accepted day="13" month="12" year="2001"/>) `

Comment: I see that that data is not present in the JSON format. That is weird, I was expecting it. I think that you could get the data in XML and parse it from there, can you do that?

Comment: thanks again,i find the problem,just change "application/json" into "application/xml", and it worked!

Comment: Yes, with that parameter you are going to get the XML instead of the JSON. As I said, it depend on what you feel more comfortable to use. In the XML you will find the date you were looking for